# Cannot get browser width when initialize page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to get the width of client browser so that I can adjust the contents of my webpage.
After some research, I use a HiddenField with jQuery to get the width.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="SendA" Value="" />
    <script>
        document.getElementById("<%=SendA.ClientID%>").value = $(window).width();
    </script>
```

I also use a Timer to update the page every minute.

The issue is, when the page is first loaded, value of SendA remains "", but after the Timer updates the page, SendA returns the correct browser width.

Is there any way I can get the browser width when the page is first loaded?

Comment: window.onload, $(document).ready, etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
// pure JavaScript
var viewportWidth  = document.documentElement.clientWidth

// jQuery
var viewportWidth  = $(window).width()
```

Check the following documentation for more information

http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with how jQuery works, you need to wait for the document to load before running jQuery code. That's why it's a good idea to put your jQuery code either at the end of the HTML document or inside `$(document).ready`

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="SendA" Value="" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById("<%=SendA.ClientID%>").value = $(window).width();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried using pure javascript and put the HiddenField at the bottom the document, but same situation still happens.